# Reading from sys.stderr in python

Tags: python, stderr

There are countless amount of questions here about how to read from stderr and stdout of a subprocess. Is it possible to do so with the current process's stderr? I checked it and it raised an IO Error : File not open for reading.

I needed to read the stderr and get the data for further processing. Are there any ways to open the file in 'r+' mode?

One way I thought of was to override the default sys.stderr with a class like:

```
class CustomStdErr(object):
    def write(self, data):
        with open(fakestderr, 'r+') as f:
            f.write(data)

sys.stderr = CustomStdErr()
```

Are there any other ways to do it more directly?

**EDIT:** *Why I need the stderr:*
There is a thread (call it X) in the code that interacts with the main thread (call it M). The main thread has logging enabled. This is redirected to the stderr. Now, thread X's duty is to monitor stderr and *read* from it and process that for the main thread. This is, in summary, what's happening.

Comment: This really looks like an XY problem. Can you clarify why you'd want to read the stderr that your own process is writing?

Comment: One thing to note, assuming the method you are suggesting works, you should be able to replace your `CustomStdErr` with `cStringIO`.

Comment: I'm not experienced on these - but I imagine that a much simpler solution would be along the lines of: overloading the logger; giving the logger an output stream that it a custom class that both gives output to X and to stderr; and defining another output to the logger (I think loggers can output to more than one place, not sure though)

Comment: Within a given process, `stderr` is an output only stream. It simply cannot be read within the process (or, in other words, only another process can read it if redirected properly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you cannot directly do what you want. If one thread writes to the *default `sys.stderr`*, by default it will go to the terminal, and it will be impossible to another thread to read that.

But ... you can always change `sys.stderr` to any object that has a `write` method taking a string argument (extract from the doc of the Standard Python Library `sys` module : *`stderr` needn’t be built-in file objects: any object is acceptable as long as it has a `write()` method that takes a string argument. (Changing these objects doesn’t affect the standard I/O streams of processes executed by `os.popen()`, `os.system()` or the `exec*()` family of functions in the os module.)*)

In short : if you thread directly writes to `sys.stderr`, you could create a pair of pipes with `os.pipe()` affect the write end to `sys.stderr`, read the read end from the monitoring thread - than can still write to `sys.__sterr__` or to a saved value of `sys.stderr`

If you thread launches subprocesses, do use a `subprocess.Popen` object to redirect the stderr stream of the subcommand to a pipe and read it from your monitoring thread.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on *ix and you have an interactive process, you can open('/dev/tty', 'r').  This is similar to reading from stderr.  Note that open('/dev/tty", 'r+') only works in 2.x; in 3.x you need open('/dev/tty', 'r').